# Nest API iOS Errors

Tags: nest-api

I'm using the Nest Developer https://developer.nest.com/ API to create an iOS app. Does anyone know how to link the Firebase framework into my app? I keep getting linking errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FTransactionResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NestThermostatManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Firebase", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NestThermostatManager.o
  objc-class-ref in NestStructureManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-quickstart.html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the '[Link Binary With Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)' build phase in Xcode? Make sure the `Firebase.framework` is added there. Here's how to add it:

1. In the project editor, select the target to which you want to add a
   library or framework.
2. Click Build Phases at the top of the project editor.
3. Open the Link Binary With Libraries section.
4. Click the Add button (+) to add a library or framework.
5. Click the "Add Other" button below the list.
6. Search for [`Firebase.framework`](https://cdn.firebase.com/ObjC/Firebase.framework-LATEST.zip) where you downloaded and unzipped it.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: At first glance the answer now seems usable without clicking the link, so yes: that was what I was looking for :-)