# IOS Nest API OAuth client

Tags: nest-api

I am looking for example code or right steps to write an ios oauth client for Nest Api. I used google GTM oAuth client but could not get the access tokens. Any pointers for ios oAuth client and steps to use with NEST Api will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We've added sample code for iOS over [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/ios-nestdk). Have a look and let us know if you have any further questions!

Cheers,
Raymond

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment so I'll write this here and delete it later. Take a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378457/nest-api-ios-errors) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463100/nest-thermostat-api) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587781/authorization-using-git-bash) to see if it helps you out. Please let me know if you've seen this response so I can delete this or maybe somebody else can copy/paste/move this?